# Fullcalendar show available user instead of occupated users (inverted logic)

Tags: php, mysql, fullcalendar

I have a fullcalendar script that show some activities.

Each activity has a name, a start, an end time and 1 or more users associated.

I have 5 users with ID 1,2,3,4,5

Example for november calendar:

activity: MANTEINANCE from 2019-11-01 10:00:00 to 2019-11-01 14:30:00 - users associated: ID 1 and 3

activity: TEST from 2019-11-03 15:00:00 to 2019-11-04 09:30:00 - users associated: ID 4 and 5

Now I need to create another fullcalendar to show users FREE, so i'd like to show:

user with ID = 1 and 3 show from:

```
2019-11-01 00:00:00 to 2019-11-01 09:59:59
2019-11-01 14:30:01 to end of November
```

user with ID = 2 for all November

user with ID = 4 and 5 show from:

```
2019-11-01 00:00:00 to 2019-11-03 14:59:59
2019-11-04 09:30:01 to end of November
```

I don't know how to implement the logic of looking for free day of calendar instead of occuped day slot...

My example for get activities in range is:

```
function get_activities($start, $end) {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM ACTIVITIES WHERE ....";
    ....
    return $array_results_activities;
}
```

Then to get users:

```
function get_users_activity($idActivity) {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM USERS_ACTIVITY WHERE activity_ID = $idActivity";
    ....
    return $array_results_users;
}
```

The only logic solution maybe:

set for all 5 users a timeline to full month, then loop trough acitivityes where the user is busy, and split the timeline created, removing the datarange where the user is busy..in this way we create 2 chunk of the timeline....

Comment: I could be wrong, but it sounds like you're asking more about how to write a SQL query to return available times, than how to configure fullCalendar? If so, then you'll get more help by tagging this with `sql` and your appropriate DBMS (e.g. `mysql` or `sql-server`)

Comment: Or, an alternative approach could be to pass your existing event data to fullCalendar, and use inverse background events to highlight the time which is not occupied by events - see the "Inverse Backgrounds" section of this documentation page: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/background-events

Comment: P.S. your suggestion "logic" at the bottom is a pretty common way to solve this problem, yes. You take a theoretical "calendar" of potentially available time, and then remove the parts which are already occupied.

Comment: @ADyson hi thankyou for the suggest for the inverted-background, but it is not what i need. to semplify my goal I created a new post for request help how to get chunks of a month... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59325784/php-split-data-range-to-get-only-chunks-free  ...after this I hope to get a next step on my problem here