# PHP split data range to get only chunks free

Tags: php

I have a datarange in array for entire month:

```
$fullrange = array(
   "start" => "2019-12-01 00:00:00",
   "end" => "2019-12-31 23:59:59"
)
```

Now I do a search in my activities and get a result like this:

```
$array_activities = array(
  0 => array(
      "ID" => 45,
      "Name" => "Activity 1",
      "start" => "2019-12-04 10:00:00",
      "end" => "2019-12-05 17:00:00"
  ),
  1 => array(
      "ID" => 46,
      "Name" => "Activity 2",
      "start" => "2019-12-07 09:00:00",
      "end" => "2019-12-07 17:40:00"
  ),
  2 => array(
      "ID" => 65,
      "Name" => "Activity 3",
      "start" => "2019-12-10 10:00:00",
      "end" => "2019-12-15 17:00:00"
  ),
  3 => array(
      "ID" => 87,
      "Name" => "Activity 3-2",
      "start" => "2019-12-11 08:00:00",
      "end" => "2019-12-17 21:00:00"
  )

);
```

My goal is to create a new array: `$final` with all free chunks of the original datarange (entire month) with no activities, so:

```
$final = array(
  0 => array(
      "start" => "2019-12-01 00:00:00",
      "end" => "2019-12-04 09:59:59"
  ),
  1 => array(
      "start" => "2019-12-05 17:00:01",
      "end" => "2019-12-07 08:59:59"
  ),
  2 => array(
      "start" => "2019-12-07 17:40:01",
      "end" => "2019-12-10 09:59:59"
  ),
  3 => array(
      "start" => "2019-12-17 21:00:01",
      "end" => "2019-12-31 23:59:59"
  )

);
```

but i'm not very sure how to do the logic..

Comment: it's likely to be easier to do it in SQL...

Comment: @ADyson mhh i need to do it in pure php

Comment: Please share the code you are using. Are there any attempts to solve the problem?

Comment: @NicoHaase i've explained better in my new post wi example result expected: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59353210/php-get-array-of-dates-splitted-from-a-long-date-range

Comment: "i need to do it in pure php"....because? That sounds like an arbitrary restriction. What's stopping you from using SQL?

Answer (score 0):

```
$startDateInTimestamp = \DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $fullrange['start'])->getTimestamp();
$endDateInTimestamp  = \DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $fullrange['end'])->getTimestamp();
function sortBy($a, $b, $value) {
    return \DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $a[$value])->getTimestamp() - \DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $b[$value])->getTimestamp();
}

function sortByStart($a, $b) 
{
    return sortBy($a, $b, 'start');
}
function sortByEnd($a, $b) 
{
    return sortBy($a, $b, 'end');
}
usort($array_activities, 'sortByStart');
$index = 0;
$final = [];
$final[0]['startDate'] = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $startDateInTimestamp);
while (count($array_activities) > 0) {
    $array_activities = array_values($array_activities);
    $final[$index]['endDate'] = $array_activities[0]['start'];
    unset($array_activities[0]['start']);
    usort($array_activities, 'sortByEnd');
    $index++;
    $final[$index]['startDate'] = $array_activities[0]['end'];
    unset($array_activities[0]['end']);
    if(!isset($array_activities[0]['end']) && !isset($array_activities[0]['start']))     {
        unset($array_activities[0]);
    }
    usort($array_activities, 'sortByStart');
}
$final[count($final)-1]['endDate'] = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $endDateInTimestamp);


echo "<pre>";
print_r($final);
echo "</pre>";
```